# How can I fix the client code so that I get code reuse via composition?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Here's the problem. I have one abstract  base class `Editor`. I also have two subclasses `GraphEditor` and a `TreeMapEditor`. The implementation of `TreeMapEditor` basically wraps a `GraphEditor` and for now basically forwards all requests to the underlying `GraphEditor`.

```
class TreeMapEditor extends Editor{
 private final Editor wrappedEditor = createWrappedEditor();

 private createWrappedEditor(){
   return new GraphEditor();
 }

 public void doA(){  //This is the abstract class defined in Editor.
   wrappedEditor.doA();
 }

 public void doB(){  //This is the abstract class defined in Editor.
   wrappedEditor.doB();
 }

 public Editor getWrappeEditor(){
  return this.wrappedEditor ;
 }

}
```

Now my idea is to reuse the code for `GraphEditor` without really subclassing `GraphEditor`(Hence the composition) . But the client code is written to the implementation of `GraphEditor` and not merely `Editor`. How can I refactor this code here? I want all the calls belonging to `Editor` to go through the `TreeMapEditor` and only more specific calls to go through the `GraphEditor`.

The client code looks like this now:

```
public clientCode(Editor editor){
  GraphEditor graphEditor = (GraphEditor)editor;

  graphEditor .doA(); //This method belongs to Editor()
  graphEditor .doB(); //This method belongs to Editor()


  graphEditor .doC(); //This method belongs to GraphEditor() only and not to TreeMapEditor
  graphEditor .doD();//This method belongs to GraphEditor() only and not to TreeMapEditor

}
```

}

Comment: Why is the client's code written to accept only `GraphEditor`s? Is there some function specific to `GraphEditor`s that not all `Editor`s have (but that `TreeMapEditor`s do too)? If so, continue defining a new interface, making both editors implement the interface, and encourage the client to refactor the code to accept any parameter of the new interface type instead of only `GraphEditor`s.

Comment: I would like to know what is being modeled here.  We can make all kinds of extensions and implementations and so forth of classes, but each class is supposed to represent one "thing" (or "type of thing") in your programming environment.  If a TreeMapEditor is really a special case of a GraphEditor, then inheritance is appropriate and we can talk about how best to implement it.  But you seem to describe some kind of hybrid, so I would like to take a half-step back and examine what we're trying to do at a higher level.

Comment: @rcook TreeMapEditor is not really `GraphEditor` but basically uses the code of the `GraphEditor`for some of its operations.It can additionally override some of the behavior of `GraphEditor` and may add operations that belong only to `TreeMapEditor`. Making it extend the `GraphEditor` will violate the LSP principle.

Comment: The example code already uses composition to achieve your goal.  Your next move is to close the editor and applaud a completed assignment.

Comment: @DwB I have to fix the client code. Can't say it is finished.

Comment: @rcook please see the edited question and title.I hope I have made things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look for a concept between GraphEditor and your other two; is there a construct within what you're doing that could be represented by a class that extends GraphEditor but is not a full-functioned GraphEditor or TreeMapEditor?  IF there is, common code might go in it.

But I would be careful to keep to implementing a representation of something in your problem space, rather than just putting methods into classes in an inheritance hierarchy because that's where you need them.  That bottom-up style of creating classes can lead to poor design, hard to understand until someone says "Oh, he just wanted this method available here.".